# WOFF Font working on Chrome but not Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, fonts, sass

I want to use custom fonts for the elements on my web page. To do that, I've added this font face to my SCSS file

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Arcon-Regular';
   src: url(asset_path('Arcon-Regular.woff')) format("woff");
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
   font-family: 'bebas';
   src: url(asset_path('bebas.woff')) format("woff");
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
   font-family: 'lovelo_black-webfont';
   src: url(asset_path('lovelo_black-webfont.woff')) format("woff");
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;
}
```

And here is where I set the fonts for my headers

```
.frontend {
    h1 {
        font-family: 'bebas' !important;    
    }

    h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
        font-family: "lovelo_black-webfont",serif !important;
    }

    p, a, li, button, dl, dt, dd {
        font-family: 'Arcon-Regular' !important;
    }
}
```

Here is some test markup

```
<html>
<body class="frontend">
<h1> This should be Bebas </h1>
<h2> This should be Lovelo </h2>
<p> This should be Arcon </p>
</body>
</html>
```

All three work on Chrome, but Lovelo does not work on IE and I can't figure out why.

**EDIT:** Got the font from [here](http://www.fontfabric.com/lovelo-font/) and used a converter to convert it to WOFF

Comment: frontend is just a custom css class i have

Comment: Its SCSS, so it should work, right?

Comment: @AllDani.com yes it does which is why I said SCSS in the question

Comment: @AllDani.com that checks CSS syntax not SCSS syntax

Comment: Have you tried setting `font-weight: normal` on the h2–h6? If they are currently computed as bold in IE, “lovelo_black-webfont” won't apply. If that’s not the issue, I would try a different font format to rule out the woff convertor.